# Split out base stylesheet between public pages and admin dashboard

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have updated a rails app and now want to use different base styles and variables between the public pages and the admin dashboard.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

I am using SASS and have a base.scss which contains mostly typography changes and I want to use different sheets whether in public pages or admin pages.

I have a class of admin on the html tag, but using this (**html.admin h1** *for example*) overrides custom styles on the page.

Is there a way to do this based on the controller possibly?

Comment: what about having 2 different `application.scss` and two different layouts `application.html.erb`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We currently have an alternate layout for the dashboard, but as we still use a fair few styles between the layouts, is there a way to target just the base.scss sheet instead of duplicating the application.scss?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Fabrizio's comment, I've managed to resolve this.

Because two different layouts are used, I was able to create a separate application.scss sheet, import the original application.scss first and then any overrides come after. Then include the new stylesheet in the <%= stylesheet_link_tag %> instead of the original one.

I did need to add this to the assets.rb precompile, but other than that, it works like a charm!